# Use compound key as additional endpoint in eve?

Tags: python, eve

I'm developing a RESTful API to access a database of mathematical objects known as finite groups. These groups are typically described in the literature by a pair of positive integers, the one known as the size or order, the other as the index. (For each order, the valid indices are the numbers 1 through N, for some N. For example, there are 10494213 groups of order 512, which have indices from 1 to 10494213, and 15 groups of order 513, which have indices from 1 to 15.)

I have a good grip on how to make the groups accessible by their MongoDB ID, such as `/group/54e392723e7c302e2cc65e94`, but I'd like to add the ability to access them through their order and index, such as `/group/512/398742`. I can see how the `additional_lookup` property of an endpoint allows for selecting an item by selecting for the value of a single field, but is it possible to select for the value of two fields? Or is this somehow possible using subresources?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sub Resources](http://python-eve.org/features#sub-resources).

The example in the docs shows that you can setup an endpoint URL like so:

```
invoices = {
    'url': 'people/<regex("[a-f0-9]{24}"):contact_id>/invoices'
    ...
```

Which would then allow the following url to be valid:

```
people/<contact_id>/invoices/<invoice_id>
```

Looks close to what you want to achieve (replace `people` with `groups` and `invoices` with `indexes`). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @NicolaIarocci. I guess this would require making `groups` and `indexes` two separate collections? The index is currently just another field in the `groups` collection.

Comment: I guess so. The sub resource pattern is ideal for hierarchical data, while you have a flat record. Of course you can still get your record right away, just by querying with `groups?where={"group": 512, "index": 398742}`